# Error in kr20: could not find function "kr20"

Tags: r

What I supposed to do if the command kr20() on R Studio give me the response "Error in kr20(datax) : could not find function "kr20" " ?

I try to install some packages but maybe I don't know what is the package I have to install

Comment: This seems to be the only package with that function listed. It will need to be installed from github. https://rdrr.io/github/cddesja/validateR/f/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package "cddesja/validateR".

You can do this with the following code:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("cddesja/validateR")
```

Then you can either load the package using

```
library("validateR")
```

Or call on the individual function using the `::` operator

```
validateR::k20()
```